# close modal when clicking on overlay, and not the modal it self

Tags: angular

I have a modal with an overlay when it's open. I have an event on the overlay to close the modal, but its close even if I click on the modal itself.
im trying this, to only close when the overlay is clicked.

```
if (event.target.classList.contains('do-not-click-here'))
```

but I get this error.

```
Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had that problem. I used a template ref on the container for the modal and then checked for it being in the **event.path** whenever click was fired on the overlay.

**template**

```
    <div class="overlay" (click)="overlayClicked($event)">
      <div class="modal" #modal>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**component**

```
    export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('modal') modal: ElementRef;
      visible = false;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      overlayClicked(event) {
        if(event.path.indexOf(this.modal.nativeElement) === -1){
          this.visible = false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic solution!